# How to check variable in another file in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am new to Ruby and writing an IRC server using some existing code. I have searched online for a solution but since I don't really know the exact phrases I want to search for, I'm having little luck so I'll explain it as best as I can here hoping that someone can help me.

I have a file `ircclient.rb` containing:

```
        when 'oper'
            name = args.any? && args.shift.downcase
            pass = args.shift

            @oline = ServerConfig.opers.find do |oper|
                oper['login'].downcase == name && oper['pass'] == pass
            end

            if @oline
                @oper = true

                send_numeric 381, 'You are now an IRC operator'
                join ServerConfig.oper_channel if ServerConfig.oper_channel

            else
                send_numeric 491, 'Login Failed'
            end
```

This code is within:

```
class IRCClient < LineConnection
end
```

My question is how can I check whether a user is `@oper` or not but from another file?

For example I tried:

```
def join client
    @opers << client if @opered?
    @users << client
    send_to_all client.path, :join, @name
end
```

but it causes the program to crash.

### Update

Thank you for the answer, I appreciate it.

In the existing `ircclient.rb` `class IRCClient < LineConnection` I have at the start:

```
  attr_reader :nick, :ident, :realname, :conn, :addr, :ip, :host, :dead, :umodes, :server
  attr_accessor :oper, :away, :created_at, :modified_at
```

In the `ircchannel.rb` I tried to access whether a user is `@oper` or not using:

```
def join client
    @ops << client if client.opered?
    @users << client
    send_to_all client.path, :join, @name
end
```

but this caused the program to crash. I also tried:

```
def join client
    @ops << client if user.opered?
    @users << client
    send_to_all client.path, :join, @name
end
```

I guess I am making a simple mistake?

Comment: As an aside, `user.rb` containing `IRCClient` is a bit confusing. Is `@oper` on some unseen `User` class or `IRCClient`?

Answer (score 1):

Since you alreday have `attr_accessor :oper` in your class, you can just write:

```
# in the `join` method
@ops << client if client.oper
```

Comment: Possibly: `s/user/client/`, since it seems the object is an instance of `IRCClient` (despite being defined in `user.rb`).